# Javascript - cycle through xml elements and display in turn

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to create an application that will show, and periodically change, a paragraph of text (like a news article or similar).
I want the data to come from an xml file so other people can add stories/remove old stories etc.
I'm trying to get my JavaScript to populate a single html field with data from an xml file. Then after a given time, for now we'll say 4 seconds, it will change to the next piece of data.
Below is a very crude version of what I've been trying to do:

HMTL:

```
<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="text"></div>
</body>
```

XML:

```
<document>
  <text>one</text>
  <text>two</text>
  <text>three</text>
</document>
```

JavaScript:

```
var timer = setInterval(addText,4000);

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystaechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        addText(this);
    }
};

function addText(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var count = 0;
    var max = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 
    xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("text")[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    if (count < max.length) {
        count++;
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }
}

xhttp.open("GET", "XMLFile.xml",true);
xhttp.send();
```

The current problem I am experiencing is that the first xml field populates successfully, but then I get an error saying `"Unable to get property 'responseXML' of undefined or null reference"`.

Ideally what I'd also like is for the xml document to be opened everytime the function occurs, so the application doesn't have to be restarted if extra data is added to the xml file - if that makes sense (and is possible)

Comment: You'll want to put the `xhttp` stuff into its own function, and set that function as the target of the `setInterval`. Right now, 4 seconds after that first line runs, `addText` is called without the `xml` argument.

Comment: Ok that's got rid of the error I was getting, so thank you for that. However my `count` isn't incrementing.
I changed my if statement to `if (count < max.length) {
        count++;
        alert('1');
    } else {
        count = 0;
        alert('0');
    }`
and it constantly just outputs 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place `addText` in the scope of `onreadystatechange` handler. Something like this.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
       var count = 0;
       var xText = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("text");
       var max = xText.length;
       var docText = document.getElementById("text");
       function addText() {
         //docText, xText and  count are available from parent scope
          docText.innerHTML = 
             xText[(count++) % max].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
       }
       var timer = setInterval(addText,4000);
    }
};

xhttp.open("GET", "XMLFile.xml",true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Sorry to revive this - but is there anyway to make the JavaScript re-open the `xml` file each time? So for example if I add an extra two `<text>` fields, they are also displayed without having to refresh the window?

Comment: Do you mean "add extra text" on server side or on client side? In the case of server you can add `clearInterval(timer)` before `setInterval`, wrap the whole code into a `function`,  and call the function from some other code. In the case of client make `xmlDoc,  xText,  max` global and use them. No window reload required.